# Graphviz dot layout type error

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx

I want to produce a tree from root(n) to its child 2,3:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
n = "%%%%% \n% % % \n%%%%%"
G.add_edge(n,2)
G.add_edge(n,3)
nx.write_dot(G,'test.dot')
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot')
nx.draw(G,pos)
plt.show()
```

This gives error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

If I use any letter suppose `'x'` in `n` before `'%'` e.g.

```
n = "x%%%%% \n% % % \n%%%%%"
```

then I don't get the error

1. How can I change my code without editing `n` itself?
2. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that graphviz doesn't allow node IDs to start with a %?

Here is a workaround:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
n = "%%%%% \n% % % \n%%%%%"
G.add_node(1,label=n)
G.add_node(2,label=2)
G.add_node(3,label=3)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
print G.edges()
nx.write_dot(G,'test.dot')
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot')
nx.draw(G,pos)
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G,"label")
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels=labels)
plt.show()
```